# how to broadcast/multicast a service over the network for clients to discover without any need for server IP

Tags: ip-address, resources

how to broadcast/multicast a service over the network for clients to discover without any need for server IP?

how to let other clients discover the service from a server, without the client requiring the IP address of the server, similar to DHCP IP acquiring.

broadcast? multicast? how do i implement the same in ruby or any other language?

Answer (score 0):

DHCP uses broadcast address on UDP port. It is job for bsd sockets programming interface. In ruby you've got `socket` in standard library.

Answer (score 0):

There's a naming protocol called [ZeroConf](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Zero_configuration_networking) that seems to be what you need.  The main provider of it is Apple, who calls it [Bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)) (used to be called Rendezvous, but needed a name change). There are Ruby bindings. I don't know how to set up the service though; what OS will the server be living on?